# Is there isomorphism between monopartite and bipartite quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, observables, quantum-states

I know the definition of monopartite, bipartite quantum system and the fact that they are defined as Hilbert space. And I also find the theorem that any two Hilbert spaces which have the same dimensions are isomorphic, cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625690/isomorphic-hilbert-spaces-iff-they-have-the-same-dimension).

**My question**:
If there are isomorphism between monopartite system $H^1=H_{n_a\times n_b}$ and bipartite system $H^2=H_{n_a}\otimes H_{n_b}$ since $H^1$ and $H^2$ have the same dimensions, how do we distinguish monopartite system and bipartite system? ($H_n$ means n-dimensional Hilbert space.) Or one system can be monopartite or bipartite system depending on my perspective?

My think:
I'm not sure but it may be distinguished by partial trace. For example, let bipartite system $H_2\otimes H_2$ has orthonormal basis $\{|0\rangle|0\rangle, |0\rangle|1\rangle, |1\rangle0\rangle, |1\rangle|1\rangle\}$ and monopartite system $H_4$ has orthonormal basis $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle, |3\rangle\}$. We can operate partial trace to $|0\rangle|1\rangle\langle 0|\langle1|$ but it's impossible for $|3\rangle\langle 3|$.

Comment: Related: [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386701/mn-dim-hilbert-space-vs-product-of-m-and-n-hilbert-spaces?rq=1) and perhaps [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241710/the-state-space-is-somehow-defined-by-the-observables), too.

Comment: All finite dimensional complex vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic; similarly, all separable infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for helpful answers about my question and infinite dimensional case. Second link was little bit hard for me but first link solve much of my question.